# Printing indices of an array

Tags: java, printing

I'm having trouble figuring out why my `j` won't print out with the current `boolean` statement. Its only if I put `!=` will it then print `100,000-1` indices.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //array size and name
    double[] largearr; 
    largearr = new double[100000];
    double index = 0.00149;
    int j = 0;

    //population of array and the printout of the elements
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(largearr, index);
        index += 0.00149;
        // System.out.println(largearr[i] + " ");
    }

    for(j = 0; j < largearr.length; j++) {
        if(largearr[j] == 58.00122999995376) {
            System.out.println("j");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't have that value in any position of your largerarr. The first for loop in your code fills all the elements of largearr array with the newly incremented index value, and it does it 100000 times: at the end you'll have largearr filled with the last iteration's value of index, that surely isn't 58.00122999995376. So the second for loop doesn't enter the if check for any value and the program quits without printing anything.

If you could explain what are you trying to achieve maybe we could help you better.

Comment: that would explain why the != boolean works. ty

Comment: Substitute the Arrays.fill with `largearr[i] = index` and it should work.

Comment: ah right. my apologies. I am to output the first "58" in the array. It is part of my analysis of algorithms project. later i will have to count how many whole 58s are in the array.